# Delete a cell from tableView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` and a `BEMCheckBox` and I want to delete the cell when the did tap is pressed here is my code :

```
func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
    let index = tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    MenuViewController().products.removeObject(forKey: "Product\(index!.row)") // removes the cell from the database of the tableview
    tableView?.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .fade)
}
```

and here is how I get the `tableView`:

```
extension UIView {
    func parentView<T: UIView>(of type: T.Type) -> T? {
        guard let view = self.superview else {
            return nil
        }
        return (view as? T) ?? view.parentView(of: T.self)
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return self.parentView(of: UITableView.self)
    }
}
```

I get the follwing error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: `MenuViewController().products.removeObject(forKey: "Product\(index!.row)")` Is that creating a whole new `MenuViewController` object? Could you check that the object is correctly removed?

Answer (score 0):

Its related to your data source.Your data source is not updated accordingly.You should check your data source before reloading `UITableview`. It happens due to the mismatch of data item count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the table view that you are about to modify the number of items:

```
tableView?.beginUpdates()
// Perform the item and cell removal
tableView?.endUpdates()
```

Always make sure to insert/delete the same number of items in your data source as the number of cells of your table view.

You can check the decoumentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)

Comment: No, you don't need `begin-/ endUpdates` in this case. Read the documentation carefully *...if you want **subsequent** insertion**s**, deletion, and selection operation**s**...* plural, that means **multiple** operations. For a single operation it's not needed at all.